# Regex capturing opening and closing braces but should not

Tags: php, regex

I am at wits-end here. I have the following string:

```
{{"extraid":"fj09bA6K3K8u" ,"extraquantity" : 1 ,"extraitemState":"LOADED"},{"extraid2":"fj09bA6K3K8u2" ,"extraquantity2" : 2 ,"extraitemState2":"LOADED2"}}
```

and the following regex:

```
{(?!{)([\s\S]*?)}
```

which is returning

```
{"extraid":"fj09bA6K3K8u" ,"extraquantity" : 1 ,"extraitemState":"LOADED","extraid2":"fj09bA6K3K8u2" ,"extraquantity2" : 2 ,"extraitemState2":"LOADED2"}
```

WITH THE CURLY BRACES! I need the string without them, and am having brain-block. Yes, I've searched SO to no avail.
little help?
actual PHP code:

```
$re = '@{(?!{)([\s\S]*?)}@s';
                    $subst = '\\1';
                    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $innerstring);
```

which is returning what is already above. I need

```
"extraid":"fj09bA6K3K8u" ,"extraquantity" : 1 ,"extraitemState":"LOADED","extraid2":"fj09bA6K3K8u2" ,"extraquantity2" : 2 ,"extraitemState2":"LOADED2"
```

without the curly braces. And yes, in this example it would return two results. Both are coming back with the not-wanted braces.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just parsing the JSON properly?

Comment: If you just want to remove the first and last characters - `substr($str,1, -1)`

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes this is a special-use case so standard json-parsing is not giving us enough flexibilty in error checking. Not the norm but it is what it is....

Comment: @NigelRen we can, but why is the regex failing? I have something wrong in there that is probably simple, and fixing that would alleviate one more command against the string.

Comment: @JayBlanchard If the string at the top is the actual string, then that's not JSON

Comment: As far as I can tell (and JSONLint) it isn't valid JSON - should have `[` and `]` round it not `{}`

Comment: The regex is actually matching 2 items, so perhaps you are only fetching the first.

Comment: Just keep it simple https://regex101.com/r/j1EZ0c/2

Comment: Agreed @PatrickQ, just wondering why it wouldn't be JSON.

Comment: @JayBlanchard almost correct! It actually IS json, just a snip of a nested array several dimensions deep. we need to do some specialized "flattening" of the nests for automation.

Comment: @A.Guattery  Can you provide the actual PHP code that you're using, along with the desired result?

Comment: @CAustin that still leaves some curly braces which the OP does not want.

Comment: @NigelRen yes it should be two matches - but \1 capture has a single opening "{" and closing "}" wrapping each output. stumped.

Comment: @PatrickQ edited post to show php and desired result. There will be more than one result from the original string posted - the regex works fine except it includes the curly braces .

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `str_replace()` get you the result you want?

Comment: I don't know if I'm oversimplifying this... but why not just `{{(.+)}}`? Then grab the first matched group?

Comment: @jakerella that grabe the entire string between the double curly braces; there is a split in the middle with single curly closing and opening tags. We need to split them both.

Comment: The problem here is we have double braces opening and closing. The outermost braces are for the entire array. When I account for single braces it is leaving the our ones there. When I account for double braces it leaves the inner single ones between the two "arrays". ARRGH!

Comment: Why not just match `[{}]+` and replace with empty string

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT

```
\{+(.*?)\}+
```

The "+" operator set up for one or more of the same character. Finally! Thanks to all who chimed in.